# Programatically fill in GTK popup using Expect, xdotool, or similar

Tags: automation, expect, xdotool, gnome-keyring-daemon, protonvpn

**Background:**
I use `pass` to manage my passwords, with the GPG key stored externally on a YubiKey smart card, and have a fair number of scripts which invoke `pass` to automate various tasks requiring authentication.  This arrangement works great for most things, but there is one specific use-case for which it hasn't so far and which, unfortunately, comes up every time I login to a new session: automatically logging in and connecting to my ProtonVPN account, using Proton's CLI tool `protonvpn-cli`.

**The problem:**
The following is a summary of the manual workflow I'm trying to automate.  Note that I've already succeeded in automating *almost all* of these steps using `expect`; the only issue I have left is how to fill in the GTK dialog box spawned by gnome-keyring (in step 1).

1. Login to ProtonVPN: `protonvpn-cli login $username`

   - This step triggers two authentication requests: one from `gnome-keyring`, which spawns a dialog box requesting my login password, and one from `protonvpn-cli` itself, requesting my Proton account credentials.
   - I can handle the second request by `expect`ing the text of `protonvpn-cli`'s password prompt, and then `send`ing the output of the appropriate `pass` command (details in the script, included below).
   - The first request, however, is something I'm not sure how to deal with.  Automatically grabbing the login password is easy (it's stored in my `pass` vault), and I imagine one can `send` that text to the stdin of a GTK process just like any other, but I don't know how to write an `expect` command that triggers if and only if a GTK password prompt appears at a specified point in the program.  For instance, the naive approach of `expect`ing the prompt text doesn't work (since that text isn't written to stdout, or at least not the stdout of any process `expect` is aware of).
2. Connect to the VPN: `protonvpn-cli connect -f`

   - This sends a request to NetworkManager's secret agent for the appropriate network credentials.
   - By spawning the process `nmcli agent all` first, and then listening on its stdout for a password prompt, I've managed to fully automate this part of the process.

**The attempt at a solution:**
Here's the full script I referenced above.  I hacked it out pretty quickly, so it may not be pretty, but it works--except that I don't know how to `expect` something like a GTK popup, as explained above.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Expect script to automatically read VPN credentials from `pass` and enter them when prompted by `protonvpn-cli` and `nmcli`.

proc connect {passwd} {
    # Connect to ProtonVPN.  Assumes user is already logged in.

    # setup nmcli secret agent to handle password request
    # job numbers and PIDs need to be saved separately
    set agent_pid [spawn nmcli agent all]
    set agent_id $spawn_id
    expect "nmcli successfully registered as a polkit agent."

    # start protonvpn-cli process, which will send a password request to nmcli
    set proton_pid [spawn protonvpn-cli connect -f]
    set proton_id $spawn_id

    # Switch back to polkit agent for password entry
    set spawn_id $agent_id
    expect {
        "*assword*:*" {
            send "$passwd\r"
        }
    }

    # Finally, switch to proton process to listen for success or failure
    set spawn_id $proton_id
    expect {
        "Successfully connected to Proton VPN." {
            exec kill $agent_pid $proton_pid
            return 0
        }
    }

    # Timeout
    exec kill $agent_pid $proton_pid
    return 2
}

proc login {username passwd} {
    # Login to ProtonVPN.  Note that this doesn't actually connect to the VPN itself; that requires a second authentication step.

    set pid [spawn protonvpn-cli login $username]

    expect {
        "*assword:*" {
            send "$passwd\r"
            expect {
                "Successful login." {
                    return 0
                }
            }
            # Login failed
            exec kill $pid
            return 1
        }
        "You are already logged in." {
            return 0
        }
    }

    # Timeout
    exec kill $pid
    return 2
}

proc print_errormsg {code} {
    switch $code {
        1 {
            puts "Issue: failed to authenticate"
        }
        2 {
            puts "Issue: timeout"
        }
    }
}

proc read_passfile {address dictname} {
    # Read output from a password file managed by `pass` and assign text to the keys of a dictionary based on my personal passfile format convention.
    # The convention is:
    #     * first line of passfile is the actual password
    #     * subsequent lines are key-value pairs in the form "key: value" (e.g., "username: user123")
    
    # Indirection (local_dict is a reference to dictname)
    upvar $dictname local_dict
    
    # This is pretty hacky, but it works
    set rawtext [exec pass show $address | sed "1s/^/password: /"]
    foreach line [split $rawtext "\n"] {
        set words [split [string map {":" {}} $line] " "]
        if { [llength $words] == 2 } {
            eval dict set local_dict $words
        }
    }
    return $local_dict
}

set timeout 30

# Get credentials from `pass`
set proton_info [dict create]
set network_info [dict create]
read_passfile personal/proton proton_info 
read_passfile wifi/vpn/proton network_info

# Login to ProtonVPN.  On the first run after logging into a new session, this spawns a GTK dialog box requesting my login password that I haven't figured out how to deal with in this script.
set login_result [login [dict get $proton_info username] [dict get $proton_info password]]
if { $login_result != 0 } {  
    puts "Login failed!"
    print_errormsg $login_result
    exit 1
}
puts "Login succeeded.  Connecting to VPN network..."

# Connect to VPN.  This part works fine.
set connect_result [connect [dict get $network_info password]]
if { $connect_result != 0 } {
    puts "Failed to connect to VPN network!"
    print_errormsg $connect_result
    exit 2
}
puts "VPN connection succeeded."
exit 0
```

Comment: [tag:expect] can only interact with CLI programs. it cannot handle GUI.

Comment: Makes sense.  Is there a way to use it to handle CLI input/output, and have it invoke another tool (xdotool?) at the appropriate point to handle the popup?